# Brownian motion increments

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

We know that if $W_t$ is a Brownian motion, $W_{t+t_0}-W_{t_0}$ is one too.

Does the "converse" holds : Let $t_0$ be a positive number. I have a Brownian motion $W_t$
and I seek another Brownian motion, $W^*$ such that $W_t=W^*_{t+t_0}-W^*_{t_0}$ does such Brownian motion exists ?

Answer (score 1):

Start with a Brownian motion $Y_t$, where the processes $W$ and $Y$ are independent.  Take 
$$ W^*_t = \cases{ Y_t & for $0 \le t \le t_0$\cr
                    Y_{t_0} + W_{t-t_0} & for $t > t_0$\cr} $$